# Isn't the "tailwind" tag the same as the "tailwind-css" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Today I noticed that the [tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind) tag is the same as the [tailwind-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind-css) tag, so shouldn't we merge both tags? the [tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind) tag doesn't improve anything, currently, it has 103 questions and no wiki. And the [tailwind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind) tag should be a synonym of the [tailwind-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind-css) tag.

Comment: I got them down to 95 question.

Comment: I think you're right. No need to go retagging since a mod can easily make it a synonym. But also, why do we have a [tag:tailwind-in-js] tag?

Comment: @Laurel As far as I see the tailwind-in-js is all about problems of tailwind and js (like the dropdown doesn't work) so yeah, I guess it needs retagging.

Comment: Tags merged and [synonym created](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tailwind-css/synonyms). The synonym can still be removed if it's causing problems with some other tailwind-related tag later.

Comment: @HenryEcker Can you take a quick look at [tailwind-in-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tailwind-in-js) because looks like it needs retagging either? And thanks!

Comment: Hm... I don't know enough to say that that tag isn't trying to refer to something separate. Tailwind and Tailwind-css clearly referred to the same thing, but I'm unsure if tailwind-in-js is supposed to refer to utilities like [this one](https://github.com/tw-in-js/twind) and that makes it in some way distinct from tailwind itself.

Comment: @HenryEcker Looks like it needs another question to discuss it, anyway thanks for your time.